# Read content of .txt file from URL

Tags: vb.net, web-scraping

I want to read the content of a .txt file from a URL.

The .txt file content is:

> 170000082.zip

I am currently using this:

```
Dim address As String = "http://linktotxt"
Dim client As WebClient = New WebClient()
Dim reader As StreamReader = New StreamReader(client.OpenRead(address))
Label1.Text = reader.ReadToEnd
```

But it set Label1.Text value to a HTML code and not the content of the txt file.

I do not want to download the txt file locally then read the text of it, I want to get it from the URL.

Any help would be appreciated!

EDIT: Here is the HTML file content:

```
<html><body><script type="text/javascript" src="/aes.js" ></script><script>function toNumbers(d){var e=[];d.replace(/(..)/g,function(d){e.push(parseInt(d,16))});return e}function toHex(){for(var d=[],d=1==arguments.length&&arguments[0].constructor==Array?arguments[0]:arguments,e="",f=0;f<d.length;f++)e+=(16>d[f]?"0":"")+d[f].toString(16);return e.toLowerCase()}var a=toNumbers("f655ba9d09a112d4968c63579db590b4"),b=toNumbers("98344c2eee86c3994890592585b49f80"),c=toNumbers("b8ff12f43c40961786132a275820f477");document.cookie="__test="+toHex(slowAES.decrypt(c,2,a,b))+"; expires=Thu, 31-Dec-37 23:55:55 GMT; path=/"; location.href="http://I_REMOVED_IT_SORRY/lastfilename.txt?i=1";</script><noscript>This site requires Javascript to work, please enable Javascript in your browser or use a browser with Javascript support</noscript></body></html>
```

Thanks! :-)

Comment: Are you sure it's a text file and not just an HTML page that have only text? Also, have you checked the returned HTML. Maybe it's telling you some kind of error.

Comment: Yes! it is "getlast.txt"

Comment: Is it by any chance a DropBox URL? Would it be possible for us to see the link?

Comment: @MatrixCow08 that means nothing. the server could be "_lying_" to you about that.

Comment: I added the HTML code in the question above.

Comment: The url from which you are retrieving that text file is meant to be seen via a browser and actually require javascript to load. You will need to get a url to the _raw_ text file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, The same code worked on my new server :-)

Everything is solved now, it was a server problem.

Answer (score 1):

When you visit that address in your browser, the web server first returns html, **not** a text file. What you're seeing is *exactly* what you should see after downloading the contents of that address. This html then tells the browser to also download and run some additional javascript (`aes.js`). It's this javascript that will finally download your text file.

You need to look at the the javascript or monitor your session using your browser's dev tools and find the real address for the text file (possibly `http://I_REMOVED_IT_SORRY/lastfilename.txt?i=1`).

Comment: Adding ?i=1 now require loading ?i=2 and so on...
I added `        client.Headers(HttpRequestHeader.UserAgent) = "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.1; .NET CLR 2.0.50727)"
        client.Headers.Add("Cookie", "__cookieforusage=b8ff12f43c40961786132a275820f477")
` but still not working.